# Reject data load attempt to BigQuery for existing data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm loading data from pandas dataframes to BigQuery using pandas-gbq package:

```py
df.to_gbq('dataset.table', project_id, reauth=False, if_exists='append')
```

A typical dataframe looks like:

```
key      |    value    |    order
"sd3e"   |     0.3     |    1
"sd3e"   |     0.2     |    2
"sd4r"   |     0.1     |    1
"sd4r"   |     0.5     |    2
```

Is there a way to reject the loading attemp if the key already appears in the BigQuery table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to reject the loading attempt if the key already appears in the BigQuery table?

No, since BigQuery doesn't support keys in a similar way other database does. 
There are 2 typical use-cases to solve this:

**Option 1:**
Upload the data with a timeStamp and use a merge command to remove duplicates

See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) on how to do this, This is an example

```sql
MERGE `DATA` AS target
USING `DATA` AS source
ON target.key = source.key
WHEN MATCHED AND target.ts < source.ts THEN 
DELETE
```

Note: In this case, you pay for the merge scanning but keep your table row unique.

**Option 2:**

Upload the data with a timestamp and use `ROW_NUMBER` window  function to fetch the latest record, This is an example with your data:

```sql
WITH DATA AS (
    SELECT 'sd3e' AS key, 0.3 as value,  1 as r_order, '2019-04-14 00:00:00' as ts  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sd3e' AS key, 0.2 as value,  2 as r_order, '2019-04-14 01:00:00' as ts  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sd4r' AS key, 0.1 as value,  1 as r_order, '2019-04-14 00:00:00' as ts  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sd4r' AS key, 0.5 as value,  2 as r_order, '2019-04-14 01:00:00' as ts  
)

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key order by ts DESC) rn 
    FROM `DATA` 
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

This produces the expected results as follow:
[image]

Note: This case doesn't incur extra charges, however, you always have to make sure to use window function when fetching from the table

Comment: thx for your quick reply!...I managed to remove the duplicates by following your suggestions..although, since the answer to my question is "no", I think I will use pandas duplicated() method instead..