# How do I continuously merge two datasets with the same schema together without duplicating rows?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

On Google Cloud Platform, I have multiple billing accounts. For each billing account, I created a scheduled export to BigQuery that executes multiple times a day.

However, I'd like to have an overview of all of my billing accounts. I want to create a master data table with all of my billing accounts combined.

All of the data tables have the exact same schema. Some sample fields:

```
cost:FLOAT
sku:STRING
service:STRING
```

I have already successfully joined my two data tables with a JOIN query:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1`
UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2`
```

After I've made this query, I clicked "Save results" --> "BigQuery Table." However, I believe this is just a one-time export.

I'd like to update this on a regular basis (say, once every 3 hours) without duplicating the entries.

How do I continuously combine these data tables while making sure I don't have duplicate rows? In other words, for new entries that come into both tables, how do I just append only those new entries to my new master table?

Comment: See if the examples in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples help. Without knowing the schema of these tables, it's hard to provide an answer.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard thanks, I'm looking into the docs now. Let me update the question with a sample schema. Both tables have the same exact schema.

Comment: Hi Ching you cant avoid duplicate during insert you will have to merge your table post insert based on a key. See an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55673711/1031958.

Comment: @TamirKlein The docs provided above look like the correct path forward. I have a separate syntax question that needs to be answered before I can fully solve this. That question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000168/how-do-i-insert-columns-with-nested-name-syntax-ie-item-description

Answer (score 1):

Use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select * from `TABLE 1`
    union all
    select * from `TABLE 2`;
```

This will always be up-to-date, because the tables are referenced when you query them.

Note:  You can create the view using the BQ query interface by running the query and selecting "create view".  Actually, you don't need to run the query, but I always do just to be sure.