# How do I INSERT columns with nested name syntax (ie. "item.description")?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to merge two databases with the same schema on Google BigQuery.

I'm following the merge samples here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

However, my tables have nested columns, ie "service.id" or "service.description"

My code so far is:

```sql
MERGE combined_table
USING table1
ON table1.id = combined_table.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(id, service.id, service.description)
  VALUES(id, service.id, service.description)
```

However, I get the error message: `Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "."`, and a red squiggly underline under `.id` on the `INSERT(...)` line.

Here is a view of part of my table's schema:

```
[
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "name": "service",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "name": "description",
                "type": "STRING"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "cost",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    }
...
]
```

How do I properly structure this INSERT(...) statement so that I can include the nested columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.

It turns out when referencing the top level of a STRUCT, BigQuery references all of the nested columns as well. So if I wanted to INSERT `service` and all of it's sub-columns (service.id and service.description), I only have to include `service` in the `INSERT(...)` statement.

The following code worked:

```
...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(id, service)
  VALUES(id, service)
```

This would merge all sub columns, including `service.id` and `service.description`.

Answer (score 2):

> Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "."

Looks like you are on the right direction, Note in the documentation how you need to insert value to a REPEATED column,

You need to define the structure to guide BigQuery what to expect, For example:

```sql
STRUCT<created DATE, comment STRING>
```

This is the full example from the documentation

```sql
MERGE dataset.DetailedInventory T
USING dataset.Inventory S
ON T.product = S.product
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND quantity < 20 THEN
  INSERT(product, quantity, supply_constrained, comments)
   -- insert values like this
   VALUES(product, quantity, true, ARRAY<STRUCT<created DATE, comment STRING>>[(DATE('2016-01-01'), 'comment1')])

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(product, quantity, supply_constrained)
  VALUES(product, quantity, false)
```

Comment: I can see the example uses the `ARRAY<STRUCT<...` syntax in the `VALUES(...)` line. But how is it used in the `INSERT(...)` line? Actually, I should've asked the question this way, although this is a completely different question: How do I include all columns in the `INSERT` / `VALUES` lines, since both tables have the same exact schema anyways?

Comment: Well in the insert you put your column name and in the values the structure and the values you want to insert

Comment: I'm trying `INSERT(service STRUCT<id>)`, but a red squiggly comes under `STRUCT<id>`. I think the ARRAY<STRUCT<...>> syntax works for `VALUES(...)`, but not `INSERT(...)`. The error message says `Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got keyword STRUCT at [8:38]`